# SAS Stored Process won't connect to Hive2 DB

Tags: stored-procedures, hive, sas

I have a code that connect successful through a libname to a Hive2 DB authenticated with kerberos:

```
libname hdb hadoop server="server-name" port=10000 schema="schema-name";
```

I have tested the code using Data Integration Studio and BASE, but when I call the same code with and the same user (checked putting in the code a `%put &=SYSUSERID;` and running in `pipe a echo %username%`) with a stored procedure the libname gives me error :

```
ERROR: Error trying to establish connection: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri:
jdbc:hive2://"server-name":10000/"schema-name";ssl=true;principal=hive/_HOST@"dominion": GSS initiate 
failed
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the stored proc is actually executing as that user, and not as the stored procedure job runner?  It's very common for stored procedures to be run as a single account for all users, not as whatever job you are authenticating as.  If you're not 100% sure, ask your SAS administrator.  I'm not sure if that would cause this particular error, but it's my default starting point for "why does SP not run when it runs fine as regular job".

Comment: i was assuming that SYSUSERID would tell me what user is running the STP and that would be the same executing it, where i could find what is the user that it's executing the STP?